# Stop auto reload after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have set my page after scan a barcode it will separate into two autocomplete. Then Ajax will send data to database to get some result, after get result it will send to autocomplete value.

My problem comes here, after data separate my page become auto reload, why?

```
$("#model").change(function() {
         var barcode;
         barCode=$("#model").val();
         var data1 = $("#model").val(barCode.substr(0,barCode.length-8)).val();
         var data2 = $("#serial").val(barCode.substr(barCode.length-8,8)).val();

         $.ajax({
                 type:"post",
                 url:"process2.php",
                 data:"model="+data1+"&serial="+data2+"&action=checkdata",
                 cache:false,
                 async:false,
                 success: function(res){
                         $('#lotno').attr("value",res);
                         return false;
                         }
                 });

         return false;
         });
```

process2:

```
switch(postVar('action')) {
        /*check data*/
        case 'checkdata' :
                checkdata(postVar('model'),postVar('serial'));
                break;
}
function checkdata($model,$serial){
        $Mod = mysql_real_escape_string($model);
        $Ser = mysql_real_escape_string($serial);
        $Mod=strtoupper($Mod);
        $Ser=strtoupper($Ser);

        $sql="SELECT lotno
                FROM dataserial
                WHERE model='".$Mod."' AND startserial <= '".$Ser."' AND endserial >= '".$Ser."'";
        ob_clean();
        $res=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());

        $dat=mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_NUM);
        if(mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
                        echo $dat[0];
                        } else {
                        echo "No specified data";
        }
        };
```

---

I have some javascript in this page:
[settingpage](http://pastebin.com/n9thkXgL)

Comment: Why you are added this code "return this;"

Comment: @Muthukumar: sorry,typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved.
It caused by submit button (from downloaded form template).

before :

```
<button id="registerButton" type="button" class="submit"><span>Submit </span></button>
```

After :

```
<button id="registerButton" type="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span>Submit </span></button>
```

After change that it works normally. I don't know why? may be someone could explain this later.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page `process2.php` the same page with the ajax? if yes then what you need is [jQuery event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("#model").change(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     var barcode;
     barCode=$("#model").val();
     var data1 = $("#model").val(barCode.substr(0,barCode.length-8)).val();
     var data2 = $("#serial").val(barCode.substr(barCode.length-8,8)).val();

     $.ajax({
             type:"post",
             url:"process2.php",
             data:"model="+data1+"&serial="+data2+"&action=checkdata",
             cache:false,
             async:false,
             success: function(res){

                     $('#lotno').attr("value",res);

                     //return false;

             }
     });

     //return false;

     });
```

Comment: after use that my page not reloaded,but the separated data (after scan barcode or hit enter) it become empty. Like I type `$('#id').val("")` after ajax success.but actually i'm not type it.

Comment: I am sorry but I am having a hard time understanding. Can you pls. rephrase your comment?

Comment: @nunu I think the problem is the `return false`. `#model` on change will activate the `ajax and the variables`. Then you added `return false` so the value will be empty. I think that's the problem? Pls. correct me if I am wrong. I am just guessing that `#model` is the id of an input tag.

Comment: i already use `e.preventDefault` and the page not loaded.But,the data which already barcode become empty.ex: i have two textfields after change function they must be filled. but actually the textfield become empty.

Comment: @nunu remove both `return false` and keep `e.preventDefault`. The return false is whats making the value empty. Check my answer for latest code.

Comment: i try to remove `return false;` but after hit enter textfield still become empty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33544/discussion-between-nunu-and-joespina)

Comment: a `work around` would be store the values inside a variable then put the values of those variables to the proper `input tags` at the end of the script.